# Beautifulsoup scraping undetermined amount of numbered pages

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, pycharm

I’m scraping a site and iterating the numbered pages from the url, this is the code I am using:

```
base_url = '' #url of the site I’m scraping, only difference is page number at the end. 
pages = list(map(str,range(1,4))) #change range for how many pages exist 
url = base_url + pages[0]
```

It worked great for what I was doing, but I made an array of different users on the site that is functional but they all have different ending page numbers. The website itself when scraped will continue until the range is met even if there isn’t content past a certain page number. Is there a way for it to be able to stop when there isn’t content for that user so it can go to the next user in the array automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. All I had to do was look for elements that only existed on pages with content, and create an if statement in the numbered page iteration for loop to break out of the loop when the content wasn't there, and just expanded the range to a large number.